# Unable to compile U-SQL scripts using latest Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK 1.4.190703

Tags: windows, sdk, azure-data-lake, u-sql

After updating to the latest USQL SDK (v 1.4.190703) we started getting the following error when trying to compile any script:

> *** Error : (-1,-1) 'GetVersionedSdkPath: unexpected layout of SCOPE CPP SDK. SCOPE_CPP_SDK=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK. DATADIR=. SDK DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK. CppSdk.Tag=vc15.'
>    Details: 'A system failure has occurred during code generation.'
>   *** Compile failed !
>   Execution failed !

The previous version (1.4.190528) and all other previous ones work just fine. I´ve tried changing the ScopeCppSDK environment variable to use the one from visual studio 2019, but the same happens
There seems to be an issue with the C++ SDK but I couldn´t find any newer version of it, and the release notes for the U-SQL SDK don´t specify anything in particular

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: unfortunately no, had to rollback to previous working version

Answer (score 0):

Can you please delete the contents of “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\SDK\ScopeCppSDK” and reinstall USQL SDK.

If this does not help, clean installation of VS/SDK should help.

Also, you should NOT set ScopeCppSDK environment variable, unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: not sure why this would help? U-SQL sdk is working just fine, the problem is happening only with the latest nuget package
same thing happens to some colleagues with different computers, so I highly doubt it's something on my particular installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "DataPartitionedOutput" this may be the problem for VS2019 and U-SQL. Microsoft said that they will fix this in the new release in September.

Our company request Microsoft for a private fix and they give us since one of our project was depending on it.

Comment: Can you share details of this private fix?  Any way for us to apply it or does it require executing something bespoke?

Comment: It is live now, you just need to update you Visual Studio.

Comment: Appears I am getting a similar, but different error sadly as I have tried both latest VS2019 and VS2019 Preview 2 with the latest Extension